# How is the return value of application:openURL:options: used?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

Reading [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?language=objc) for `UIApplicationDelegate - application:openURL:options`

**Return:**

> YES if the delegate successfully handled the request or NO if the
>   attempt to open the URL resource failed.

What does returning `YES` vs `NO` impact? Is it just a convenience if you happen to be sub-classing your app delegate and might want to let `super` handle the invocation? The return value doesn't seem to affect the behavior of `UIApplication` itself in any obvoius way.

Comment: Are you saying that returning NO will also open the app?

Comment: Yes, returning NO also opens the app

Comment: My theory was that the return value is sent back to the calling app. So I tested: app A launches app B. B returns `NO` from `application:openURL:options:`. In `openURL:options:completionHandler:`, app A still receives a `success=YES`. So the return value of the launched app is not sent back to the calling app. Theory invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

`application:openURL:options` should be implemented if the app opens deep links including waiting for a callback from another app as facebook login.

The URL/URI parameter value should contains the needed information to let you figure out to which view controller the app should be re-directed to.

One example with facebook callback there is facebookSDK method that can be called and it will handle the URI parsing for you.

If you decide to open the app you should return YES/true, and then proceed with re-directing. Otherwise, return NO/false.

If app accepts info. from 3rd party apps. This method allow you to check the validity of this info. and regardingly accept the request or reject it.

Comment: Ok, but still unclear what difference returning YES or NO actually makes.

Comment: are you saying that even if NO is returned app opens anyway?

Comment: That's what I'm seeing on iOS 10... I call openURL: from app A, and app B returns NO in openURL:options but it is still opened.

Comment: @BenFlynn I'm seeing the same thing in iOS 13, so the return value is for no use?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application#return_value read the discussion it may help

Comment: @hsan "true if the delegate successfully handled the request or false if the attempt to open the URL resource failed." it's not specified the effect

Comment: "If only one of the two methods is implemented, its return value determines whether this method is called." got it

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Question is in what way the return value affects the system.